# Add Augmentation Layers Before keras.applications.EfficientNetB0 and Retain Layer Names

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a trained EfficientNetB0-based model with saved weights in a H5 format.

I want to add some preprocessing layers before the model, load the weights, and retrain it.

If I create a model like this:

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[224,224,3])
noise = tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev=10.)(inp)

feature_extractor = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, pooling="max")
features = feature_extractor(noise)
output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="sigmoid")(features)
output2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(output1)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, [output1, output2])
```

I get this summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_27 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_13 (GaussianN (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
efficientnetb0 (Functional)  (None, 1280)              4049571   
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 100)               128100    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1010
```

and I lose access to intermediate layers. I can't use the `tf.keras.Sequential` approach because my model has two outputs.

I want to retain the layer names inside EfficientNetB0 so that I can reload my weights. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "I lose access to intermediate layers" ? You still can access the layers of `feature_extractor` by the layer number `feature_extractor.get_layer(index=15)` or the layer name `feature_extractor.get_layer(name='block6b_bn')`

Comment: yes but loading weights from is painful since the names don't align. I want to retain the original layer names in the summary level so I can `load_weights("weights.h5", by_name=True)`

Comment: So why can't you just `feature_extractor.load_weights('weights.h5', by_name=True)`

Comment: The layer names of `feature_extractor` did not change

Comment: It's true that I could do that, but unlike my example there's quite a lot going on after the feature extractor.
I could do `model.load_weights('weights.h5', by_name=True)` and `feature_extractor.load_weights('weights.h5',by_name=True)`, but I'd like the code to be backwards compatible, it doesn't seem very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like for the toy example I created above the answer is:

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[224,224,3])
noise = tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev=10.)(inp)

feature_extractor = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(input_tensor=noise, include_top=False, pooling="max")
output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="sigmoid")(feature_extractor.output)
output2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(output1)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, [output1, output2])
```

However, I'm actually working with a custom model class that doesn't have that argument in the constructor...

Without the `input_tensor` argument is there another way to do this?